# URLs in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC app with 2 `DipsatcherServlet`s defined in web.xml as below:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>form-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/form-rest.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>admin-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/admin-rest.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Each one has a different URL-pattern:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>form-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>admin-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In one of my Controllers defined in `admin-rest.xml`, I have a method to handle requests to `/admin/login` defined like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/login", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
public String requestLoginForm() {
    return "LOGIN";
}
```

But it returns a 404 error.
It seems the URL-pattern defined in web.xml isn't playing nice with the url defined in the handler. Not sure if I need to include /admin in the Controller RequestMapping annotations because it's in the web.xml. With that in mind I've tried the following alternatives, neither of them work:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@RequestMapping(value = "login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method=RequestMethod.GET) should be the correct annotation. Can you post the exact URL you are invoking? What are you seeing in the access logs?

Comment: How exactly are you invoking your controller method ? I mean the actual url you're using to make GET request.

Comment: @christopher are you sure about that? Reading the spec, the longest match should be tried first, before using the default mapping.

Comment: The exact URL is http://localhost:8080/admin/login - the app is on local Tomcat's root webapp

Comment: So you just copied all your classes, xmls and other project files in webapps/ROOt folder ?

Comment: More or less, it's deployed using maven's tomcat plugin to /, so it does overwrite the original ROOT folder

Comment: It was me being silly. I had forgotten the @Controller annotation.